# I wan to find best set of four starting words in Wordle - how do I optimize my code?

Tags: python, optimization

I've written a piece of python code that can find the best starting words in Wordle, no problem. However, I usualy use a set of four starting words (spoke, craft, dumpy, light) and would like to know which possible set of four starting words would be best.

Finding a single starting word took the program a fraction of a second.
Finding a pair of starting words took it a half hour.

I have an optimization problem.

Where can I go to learn about this sort of optimization?

```
'''words_file = open("words.txt", 'r')
words_list = words_file.readlines()
words_file.close()'''

words_list = [line.rstrip() for line in open('words.txt', 'r')]

# print(words_list[0])

'''words_5 = []
for word in words_list:
    if len(word) == 5:
        words_5.append(word)'''

words_5 = [word for word in words_list if len(word) == 5]

# print(words_5[0:5])

squished = ''
for word in words_5:
    squished += word

# print(squished[0:20])

frequency = {'a':0, 'b':0, 'c':0, 'd':0, 'e':0, 'f':0, 'g':0, 'h':0, 'i':0, 'j':0, 'k':0, 'l':0, 
    'm':0, 'n':0, 'o':0, 'p':0, 'q':0, 'r':0, 's':0, 't':0, 'u':0, 'v':0, 'w':0, 'x':0, 'y':0, 'z':0, }
for letter in frequency:
    # print(letter)
    frequency[letter] += squished.count(letter)


betterfrequncy = {}
for letter in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
    for position in '12345':
        key = letter + position
        betterfrequncy[key] = len([word for word in words_5 if word[int(position) - 1] == letter])

#print(betterfrequncy)

#print(frequency)

def calcScore(fourWords, penalty):
    score = 0
    squish = ''
    for word in fourWords:
        squish += word
    for letter in frequency :
        score += squish[letter]
        if squish.count(letter) > 1:
            score += penalty * squish.count(letter)
    return score

def betterScore(words):
    score = 0
    squish = ''
    for word in words:
        word = word.lower()
        squish += word
    for word in words:
        word = word.lower()
        #print(word)
        for pos in range(5):
            thisKey = word[pos] + str(pos + 1)
            #print(word[pos])
            score += (squish.count(word[pos]) ** -2) * betterfrequncy[thisKey]

    return score

#print(betterScore(['spoke', 'craft', 'dumpy', 'light']))

print('Crane')
print(betterScore(['Crane']))

top_score = 0
top_word = ''
for word in words_5:
    if top_score < betterScore([word]):
        top_word = word
        top_score = betterScore([word])

print(top_word)
print(top_score)
```

My second attempt:

```
words_list = [line.rstrip() for line in open('words.txt', 'r')]

words_5 = [word for word in words_list if len(word) == 5]

betterfrequncy = {}
for letter in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
    for position in '12345':
        key = letter + position
        betterfrequncy[key] = len([word for word in words_5 if word[int(position) - 1] == letter])


def betterScore(words):
    score = 0
    squish = ''
    for word in words:
        word = word.lower()
        squish += word
    for word in words:
        word = word.lower()
        #print(word)
        for pos in range(5):
            thisKey = word[pos] + str(pos + 1)
            #print(word[pos])
            score += (squish.count(word[pos]) ** -2) * betterfrequncy[thisKey]

    return score

run = 0
top_score = 0
top_words = []
for word1 in words_5:
    run += 1 
    print("{:.3f}%".format((run / len(words_5)) * 100))
    for word2 in words_5:
        test_words = [word1, word2]
        if top_score < betterScore(test_words):
            top_words = test_words
            top_score = betterScore(test_words)
            
print(top_words)
print(top_score)
```

Comment: This does not answer you query but you might want to look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v68zYyaEmEA which deals with the same issue in a clever way and uses Python, and a follow-up  which changes the conclusion.